# github webhook to trigger job on multiple jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, github, webhooks

My scenario:

- Single github repo
- 4 files in the repo
- 4 jenkins server

Desired outcome:

- pushing changes in file A, should trigger job in jenkins server A, pushing changes in file B, should trigger job in jenkins server B and so on.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending where your repository is hosted (github, gitlab, bitbucket) you might be able to use a pipeline within the repository to look for the changed files and trigger a webhook on the correct server accordingly.

Another approach could be to always trigger a special job on server A which then looks for changed files and triggers the correct job on the right server.

Comment: I am using gitHub.

Comment: in that case you can use github actions to check for the changed file (some shell magic should do here) and then trigger the right server with something like this https://github.com/marketplace/actions/http-request-action